# Adafruit Micro-SD breakout not initializing on MEGA 2560

Tags: spi, sd-card, adafruit, atmega2560

[image: Micro-SD breakout]]
[[image: Connection to MEGA]I am having quite a bit of trouble trying to get my Arduino MEGA 2560 to read my micro-SD card. My wiring is as follows:

```
Breakout    Arduino
5v            5v
Gnd           Gnd
CLK           52
DO            50
DI            51
CS            53
CD            Was not connected and then connected to 47 (neither worked)
```

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h> //library necessary to use I2C communications bus
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME680.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>

const uint8_t chipSelect = 53; //chipSelect pin for the SD card Reader
const uint8_t cardDetect = 47;

File CO2Data; //Data object you will write your sensor data to

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);//"begins" the serial monitor so you can print stuff out when connected to the computer (set baud rate to 115200)
Wire.begin ();//begins the I2C communications bus so it can talk to the K33

Serial.print("Initializing SD car...");
pinMode(53, OUTPUT); 

if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
// don't do anything more:
while (1) ;
}
Serial.println("card initialized.");
File CO2data = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
if (! CO2data) {
Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
// Wait forever since we cant write data
 while (1) ;
}}
```

The SD card is formatted to FAT32.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: try the CardInfo example

Comment: I did try to cardinfo example and came up with the following message:Initializing SD card...initialization failed. Things to check:
* is a card inserted?
* is your wiring correct?
* did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?

Comment: Update: I set chipselect  to 10 in the Cardinfo example and card is found and present. However, it still won't run in my sketch. I have gone through trying different pin combinations.

Comment: do you have some shield on the Mega or some other devices wired to it?

Comment: I do, I have a couple of things wired to the MEGA: Adafruit BME680 (temp pressure) using the I2C interface (SCL wired to 21 and SDA wired to 20) and a KC-30 CO2 sensor wired to pins 10 and 9.

Comment: SOLVED: The non-analog ground line attached to the micro-SD was pulling down my voltage. Just hardwired to different ground and problem solved!  (Check your voltages)

Comment: what is a non-analog ground in this case?

Comment: From what I could gather. the ground pin on the MEGA inline with the digital pins was a different ground source (digital ground). I literally took the ground lead from the SD board and just touched it to the housing of the USB connector on the MEGA and my voltage came back.

Comment: did you try one of the ground pins between 5 V pin and Vin pin?

Comment: I tested the Vin on the micro-SD between the ground on my voltage regulator board (which drops battery incoming from 12 and outputs 5 to the MEGA), it read fine. But when measuring between the Vin pin on the Micro-Sd and the ground on the micro-Sd my voltage was only 1.5.  So I just reran that ground wire.

Answer (score 1):

The non-analog ground line attached to the micro-SD was pulling down my voltage. Just hardwired to different ground and problem solved! (Check your voltages).

From what I could gather. the ground pin on the MEGA inline with the digital pins was a different ground source (digital ground). I literally took the ground lead from the SD board and just touched it to the housing of the USB connector on the MEGA and my voltage came back.

Comment: It's OK to accept your own answer as the solution to the problem.